# how to convert snowflake discord id to date in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to convert discord user id to date, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet

I have this little code created in python

```
import datetime

def snowflake_time(id):
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(((id >> 22) + 210801244770402304) / 1000)
```

But it's not working

Could someone help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the incorrect value to the timestamp part.

According to the [Snowflake ID Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_ID), all dates start at the Twitter Epoch, which is `1288834974657` milliseconds from the Unix Epoch. Thus, to convert a Snowflake ID timestamp into milliseconds from the Unix Epoch, simply add `1288834974657`.

In your code, you add `210801244770402304`. I'm not sure where you're getting this number, but it is incorrect. This code worked for me:

```
import datetime


def snowflake_time(snowflake):
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(((snowflake >> 22) + 1288834974657) / 1000)


print(snowflake_time(1541815603606036480))  # => 2022-06-28 16:07:40.105000
```

Comment: it becomes blank, how do I add the user id to display the date?
https://i.imgur.com/gY29JHn.png

Comment: @paulita You need to call and print the result. I just added an example in my answer.

Comment: @paulita If my answer was helpful, then please consider also upvoting it to further indicate that it is useful. Happy to help!

Comment: yes, vote now, thank you very much for your help